How to search by first name and last name in users.php
So I need to be able to search users by their names in users.php. Wordpress only looks for the username by default. There is an action, pre_user_query, that allows you to edit the WP_User_Query and add whatever criteria you may need. On a normal Wordpress, it works perfectly. However, when used on a multisite, the search results page is behaving strangely.
When I lookup the name Nick for example, I am greeted with a singular result even if there are multiple users named Nick, or other names containing the string (like Yannick for example). Even stranger, the pagination shows that there are 300+ pages, even though the results only displays one. If I change page, the same result is displayed.

Here is the code I have for this
add_action('pre_user_query','extend_user_search');
function extend_user_search( $u_query ) {
    if ( $u_query->query_vars['search'] ) {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $search_query = trim( $u_query->query_vars['search'], '*' );

        // Adding first name to the search
        $u_query->query_from .= " JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} fname ON fname.user_id = {$wpdb->users}.ID AND fname.meta_key = 'first_name'";

        // Adding last name to the search
        $u_query->query_from .= " JOIN {$wpdb->usermeta} lname ON lname.user_id = {$wpdb->users}.ID AND lname.meta_key = 'last_name'";

        $search_by = array( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'fname.meta_value', 'lname.meta_value' );

        $u_query->query_where = $u_query->get_search_sql( $search_query, $search_by, 'both' );
    }
}

I tested it on a standard Wordpress, and it does work fine. The problem really does seem to be with multisites installation. The users are all assigned to the one specific blog I am trying this code in.
For reference, I got this initial solution from this article, and it seems that I'm not the only one having this problem. The comments are closed now so I wasn't able to ask if anyone had a solution.
Does anyone have an idea why this problem is exclusive to multisites and how to solve it?

There's a filter called user_search_columns, have you tried that? Whether it plays nice with multisite I don't know, and the docs don't appear to say anything either.

It would work perfectly if not from the fact that I need to search by first_name and last_name. user_search_columns only seems to look in the data from the users table. Unfortunately, first_name and last_name are both in the usermeta table. But that was very close to solving my problem

This might be a case where it is easiest to inspect all of the queries that WordPress runs for your situation. I think you are either affecting too many queries, or not enough queries, but I don't have a multisite install handy to help diagnose further.

Use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN also use AS fname and AS lname ?

Unfortunately changing it to a LEFT JOIN ended up taking all the memory and crashing the page when I searched for something. There may be too many users on the site for that to be viable.
